# Open all InfoWindows on a Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I know there's a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719441/get-all-infowindows-on-a-google-map) about this, but the problem is still unresolved and seems like such a trivial thing one may want: for a given Google Map, with data coming from a Fusion Tables layer, I'd want to open all InfoWindows (tooltips) simultaneously.

Currently, you can open them individually by clicking each region on the map. The desired result would be like clicking them all while they stick around (not letting them close each other).

My goal is to show the map with all this information visible, not needing any interaction. I'm not aware of an easier way of showing labels in Google Maps, but I'd be delighted to hear another ways to approach it. At this point, I'd settle for not letting each InfoWindow close the rest, so then I could manually open them one after another.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a direct way to do this as the FusionTableLayer doesn't expose the underlying structure of the data until you click on a feature.

Depending on the number of rows in the table, you could use Google Chart Tools to load the table directly, up to 500 rows, and generate your own infowindows based on the data returned. That is easy for point data, not as easy for polygons or polylines as you have to determine where to place the infowindow. And if you table uses geocoded data you will have to re-geocode them. If it uses KML you will have to parse the individual KML features in each row to determine where to place the infowindow.

So, it's doable but not super easy.